# heatmap on ggmap error and best practice

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, gstat, kriging

I want to plot a heatmap on a ggmap.

```
  library(ggmap)
  turku<-get_map('turku', zoom=13)
  turkumap<-ggmap(turku, extent="device", legend="topleft")
  turkumap
  turkumap+geom_density2d(mapping=aes(x = lon, y = lat),data = test, )
```

the error i get is:

```
 Error in (function (x, y, h, n = 25, lims = c(range(x), range(y)))  : 
 bandwidths must be strictly positive
```

The test variable is:

```
  test
         lon     lat var1.pred
  1  22.25320 60.4314 -67.04862
  2  22.25332 60.4314 -67.07793
  3  22.25344 60.4314 -67.11007
  4  22.25356 60.4314 -67.14517
  5  22.25368 60.4314 -67.18336
  6  22.25379 60.4314 -67.22478 
  7  22.25391 60.4314 -67.26956
  8  22.25403 60.4314 -67.31783
  9  22.25415 60.4314 -67.36973
  10 22.25427 60.4314 -67.42537
```

Suggestions?
The variable test has many more entries, What i want to plot is the result of kriging, obtained through the function krige in the gstat library.

Is there a better way to do it?

I am open to very different solutions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `lat` values are all the same. This means that the variance in the `lat` direction is zero, so a bandwidth for the kernel density estimate can't be calculated

You can hard code a bandwidth,

```
turkumap + geom_density2d(mapping=aes(x = lon, y = lat),
                 data = test, h=0.01)
```

but in your case I would suggest not using `geom_density2d` for this particular data set. Perhaps just plotting the points?

Comment: I edited the question because my point did not fit in the comment space. Hope it is ok.

Comment: @Irene I would remove the comment and ask another separate question about this specific issue.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891922/r-heatmap-on-ggmap-from-kriging-data