# r heatmap on ggmap from kriging data

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, gstat, kriging

I want to plot a heatmap on a ggmap.

```
  library(ggmap)
  turku<-get_map('turku', zoom=13)
  turkumap<-ggmap(turku, extent="device", legend="topleft")
  turkumap
  turkumap+geom_density2d(mapping=aes(x = lon, y = lat),data = test, )
```

We have made a measurement campaign, so I have 4460 geo-referentiated points.

To have a prediction map, I created a grid 400*400, for a total of 160000 points in which I calculate the prediction with kriging. 
To have a full picture of the phenomenon in my 3 km *3 km i think some kind of heat map is necassary because plotting only the points, if I am not
doing anything wrong plots a filled square on the map. (See [file](http://www.mediafire.com/?6bd51x6xkp5e3h7))
The code I use to plot the points is:

```
turkumap <- turkumap + geom_point(data=temp, aes(x=lon, y=lat),size=var1.pred)
```

So basically the problem is that the points are along roads, so a heat map is problematic 
(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888048/heatmap-on-ggmap-error-and-best-practice)) and there are too many to plot them singularly.
Any suggestions?

The other related question is that my data are in the classical format of gstat, SpatialPointsDataFrame, this means that I have to coerce them to be dataframes to use
ggplot, is there a better practice?

Comment: In response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285415/density2d-plot-using-another-variable-for-the-fill-similar-to-geom-tile/) somebody posted a fully worked example of how to bin your data and plot it in `ggmap` with the colour scales of your choice over a map. You may well find some ideas there. And if you're using `ggplot` you do need a data frame, so you pretty much have to use `fortify`.

Comment: Thank you! I spent so much time searching before posting, but I did not see that entry.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by @SlowLearner solved my issue